# Where in the wider Frankfurt am Main area is this (closed?) railway bridge?

Tags: germany, identify-this

In the film [Live (2020)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8554982/) ([alternate link including stream](https://online.lichter-filmfest.de/film/live/)), after about 1 hour 9 minutes, there is a scene on a railway bridge that is part of what is probably a museum/heritage narrow-gauge railway, or abandoned altogether.  Most of the rest of the film is shot in the vicinity of Frankfurt am Main, Germany, so this shot probably is too.  Other shots just before this scene contain a tunnel with tracks still present.  Where is it?

Unfortunately, the shot is at night, but this being a [nuit américaine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuit_am%C3%A9ricaine) some shapes can still be recognised, probably enough to identify it for someone knowing the place.

This is a still from the film at 01:08:49 (click for a larger version):

[image: still from film Live (2020) at 01:08:49, showing a railway bridge by night]

The other nearby shot, apparently in a tunnel, perhaps from the same railway (at 01:06:44):

[image: still from the same film at 01:06:44, showing a railway tunnel by night]

Comment: One can get a pretty good (but really nondescript) picture of the bridge by adjusting the colours. For the tunnel the picture is a bit weirder, but shows an inner rail of some sort on the right side, not sure if that could be a hint.

Comment: I see rails in the second picture. Are you sure the railway is abandoned?

Comment: @KristvanBesien in the US at least the cost of removing rails from abandoned railways is not justified by the benefits, so the presence of rails is not a good way of determining whether a given railway is in use.

Comment: @phoog in Germany when a railway is abandoned the rails usually quickly disappear in the vegetation. That line in the second picture looks like it is still in use.

Comment: @KristvanBesien No, I'm not sure.  On second thought, it's probably a heritage/museum railway.  I've edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it is [Himbächel-Viadukt (German Wikipedia)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himb%C3%A4chel-Viadukt).

It is located in the Odenwald. And the Odenwaldbahn ist still traversing it.

Comment: Then the film makers must have tricked us and the adjecent shots are somewhere totally different.  That's what film makers do :)

Comment: @gerrit haha, in "A-Team' they parachute to the Frankfurt Main station. But what we see is the Main station in Cologne.

Comment: @gerrit that reminds me of a movie that was shot in my grandparents' town in which the characters are driving from one part of town to another -- a drive of maybe 5 or 10 minutes.  Along the way, they pass by an old ruined church that is 30 km away.